# HTML table with JSOUP

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have a code to scape html table- the code works fine with other websites except for Morningstar. Please assist, Not sure what I'm missing. The code looks like this;

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class WebScrapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
final String url="https://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.htmlt=0P0000MPIU&culture=en&platform=sal";
        
        
        try {
            
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            org.jsoup.select.Elements rows = doc.select("table.r_table1.text2 tr");
                for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element row : rows) {
                        org.jsoup.select.Elements columns = row.select("td");
                            
                        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element column : columns) {
                                    System.out.print(column.text());
                        }
                   System.out.println();
                }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors does it prints? What's the input (for us behind firewalls), what's the desired output?

Comment: @DDS - There is no error, the program runs fine  with other tables on other websites and it prints row data. However, with morningstar table (r_table1.text2) it runs but returns nothing